# Handling duplicated files in multi-computer backups to online services

Tags: backup

I am wondering if there is a relatively convenient way of doing multi-machine backups to an online backup service without incurring the cost of storing the same files multiple times. I am not asking for providers that have unlimited upload limits here, btw, as that is just circumventing the actual issue.

My use case:

- server in location A
- server in location B
- desktop computer at location C
- laptop at location D
- desktop computer in location D

Many of these computers have the same files on them. For instance, I keep all photos backed up at the server in location, but I also work on them at computers in location C and D, synced using `rsync` to the server. That's 800GB of photos using 2400GB of backup space at my online backup provider, which is causing me to get throttled speeds :-/ So now I want to rethink how I am doing backups. Maybe I could run some kind of backup server on a server and then do backups of *it* to an online provider. Not sure what kind of software what handle de-duplication across different machines/clients, though. Duplicati or duplicity? No idea.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try [`backuppc`](https://backuppc.github.io/backuppc/), which does it natively. It stores each file just once and uses symlinks from the different backups (different hosts or backups of the same host done at different times).

It supports NFS, SSH, SMB and rsync, does deduplication (at file level) and compression. It can schedule backups, has a web interface and [many other features](https://backuppc.github.io/backuppc/info.html).

Comment: I might need to revisit BackupPC. BackupPC does rely on a central server which needs to be able to connect to all clients. That is probably not possible, usually, with many different locations, unless I also set up a VPN server. The inverse of this is [Duplicacy](https://duplicacy.com) where you only need a central storage, which the clients upload to, and they deal with de-duplication themselves. That should result in better performance as cpu heavy work (checksumming) is done client-side. Good tip, though!

Comment: No need for VPN. If you cannot connect the server to one of the clients, you can have the client connect to the server and then change the schedule for that host accordingly, or have the host trigger its own backup (directly or piggybacking the ssh connection for example). Check this post: [backuppc - how to backup remote (over the internet) clients?](https://serverfault.com/questions/246578/backuppc-how-to-backup-remote-over-the-internet-clients#246608).

Answer (score 0):

Cross-source deduplication?

You could write a script to access each PC you wish to back up which

- looks in specified target directories (not much need to back up everything on a PC, just its data)
- makes a list of files from that PC to consider backing up
- run a checksum on each of those files, and
- add the name of the PC to each line so you have a fully qualified path name which identifies the PC those files are on.

Repeat for every PC you wish to back up.

Concatenate the list of files from every PC into a master list.
Sort the master list on the checksum value.
If the checksum and file name match another file from a different PC, remove the duplicate line item(s) from the master list of files to back up

Now you have a list of files with no duplicates to back up.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but I wrote "relatively convenient way" ;) Backups are supposed to be restored. Good luck using that approach to restore your backups. For no apparent reason, directories would be missing random files, as they would be present in some other directory on another computer. It's not hard fixing this exact issue using hard links, etc., but I did not want to create yet another (badly written and untested) backup system - I have done that before :-) The performance would also be pretty terrible in a naiive solution. Let's not re-invent the wheel.